# Applying for a UK visa

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I was granted a 6 months visitors visa and it expired last April. I am planning to apply again. Is it okay to apply for a visitors visa again, a month and a half before my plan of travel?

Answer (score 3):

The only problem would be if the visa official thinks you are trying to spend a lot of time in the UK by using a series of tourist visas. As a general rule tourists cannot stay more than 6 months in any 12 month period.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is okay. (the text in the bracket is to reach the minimum characters)